# Confused about this usage of の

Tags: grammar, particle-の

> 日本での生活は楽しいです。

I'm not sure about the usage of の here. Is 日本で生活は楽しいです。correct?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/33605/9831