# Regarding で particle

Tags: particle-で

What is the difference between these sentences?

> インドでの格好のまま来てしまったのです

and

> インドの格好のまま来てしまったのです

What is the use of で particle?

Answer (score 1):

インドでの格好のまま来てしまったのです →
インドにいた時の格好で来た

インドの格好のまま来てしまったのです →
インドのstereotypeの格好で来た

Comment: Would you mind including the English answer as well?  I think that this question will be a good resource for other users who are just beginning their Japanese study, and it would be a shame if they were unable to read this answer.

Answer (score 1):

インドでの恰好 means "outfit/appearance when (someone was/is) in India", which only refers to whatever someone was wearing in India. This で is a location marker, and the function of の after で is explained in this question: [using の with と,で, から, まで](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/33605/5010) On the other hand, インドの恰好 is ambiguous, and it may refer to traditional Indian costume such as turban and sari if there were no context at all.