# Does this saying make sense? (Kurayami kara Hikari or 暗闇 から光)

Tags: translation, word-choice, sentence

I'm trying to convey the message "Light from Darkness" or "Light out of Darkness" so I came up with the saying "Kurayami kara Hikari" or "暗闇 から光". Or is this too simple and it should be "暗闇からの光"? I'm just wondering if this would make sense in the context of Japanese language. Like if this was on a shirt would it convey the message I'm intending. Or should I word it more like "Light born out of Darkness" in Japanese? And how would I say that? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

暗闇からの光 is the standard way of translating this because 暗闇から is modifying a noun, 光. See: [using の with と,で, から, まで](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/33605/5010)

However, 暗闇から光 is still correct and understood. In this case, people feel some verb is omitted because 暗闇から without の **must** modify a verb. So this phrase is like an abbreviated version of "Light *is coming* from darkness", and therefore it sounds somewhat more dynamic. [棚からぼたもち](https://jisho.org/word/%E6%A3%9A%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89%E7%89%A1%E4%B8%B9%E9%A4%85) is an idiom with the same construction (in this case a verb like "receive" or "get" is omitted).

Comment: Thank you for the helpful links, I have learned a lot from them. I think I understand why using の is the standard translation but I just want to clarify a couple things from your answer. When you say: "this phrase is like an abbreviated version of "Light is coming from darkness"" is the phrase you are referring to the form of the phrase with or without の? Also, I am not sure I want to convey that light is coming from the darkness, more that it is born out of it if that makes sense. Would these two messages be the same in Japanese or are there different ways of conveying these messages? Thanks!