# Why is there only one の in 牧師から信徒への手紙?

Tags: particles, particle-の, particle-から, particle-へ, modification

> 牧師**から**信徒**への**手紙

"a letter from a pastor to the congregation" - weblio example

shouldn't it be

> 牧師**からの**信徒**への**手紙

?

It seems to me that 牧師から and 信徒へ are modifying 手紙 independently. Is this some kind of rule where の shouldn't be repeated in such cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AからBへ and AからBまで are treated as one set, and only one の is necessary. I think this is an exception you need to remember. (I have mentioned this in [this answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/61177/5010).)