# Why there's a の in this sentence? 彼は海外での生活が長いです

Tags: particle-の

Why there's a の in this sentence?

> 彼は海外での生活が長いです

I found it reviewing my Anki 10000 cards, so I guess it's well written. Is 彼は海外で生活が長いです also correct?

Comment: Does it help? [using の with と,で, から, まで](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/33605/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the speaker of the sentence focused on what his living at foreign country is long than what he was living at foreign country.
On those occasions, we use での after a location word.

If you focused on 生活 itself,  you can use 海外で and following words will be 生活していました and so on.

彼は海外で生活していました means he was living at foreign country.
彼は海外での生活が長いです means his living at foreign country is long.

So, my answer to your question, Is 彼は海外で生活が長いです also correct?, is "It could make us sense, but we don't use a phrase like this".

Have a good learning.