# Can you imply your location without using personal pronoun?

Tags: particles, conversational

I want to say something like "I'm enjoying your music from Sendai", which can be read ambiguously even in English. The meaning I want to get across is I am in Sendai and enjoying the listener's music.

仙台の音楽を楽しんでいます。

This is what Google Translate does for me, since it's ambiguous. It suggests I like music made in Sendai.

仙台から音楽を楽しんでいます。

I'll admit I haven't encountered から yet in my study but looked ahead to get an idea of how it's used. From my understanding, it can indicate a location where what you're talking about has started. I'm not so sure it's what I'm looking for.

I want to imply my location but without specifying who is where by breaking out personal pronouns. It sounds awkward were I to be too specific like "I'm from Sendai and I'm enjoying your music".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with using で, the default location particle for actions including 楽しむ.

> 仙台で音楽を楽しんでいます。
> I'm enjoying music in Sendai. (I'm in Sendai and enjoying music.)

仙台から音楽を楽しんでいます isn't terribly wrong, but this sounds like you're a broadcaster or streamer who is trying to transmit your enjoyment from Sendai.

Note that it's guaranteed that this で (or から) modifies 楽しむ, not 音楽. [Here's why](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/33605/5010). Something like "I'll forward the letter from Canada" may be ambiguous in English ("from Canada" may modify either "forward" or "letter"). But the same problem doesn't happen in Japanese, because the noun-modifying form and the verb-modifying form are strictly distinguished.

仙台の音楽 means local/traditional music of Sendai (like [this](https://youtu.be/2GQbAHlkzxo?si=1FynnYtJa0Paool5)), so that's not what you want.

"Your music" is あなたの曲 or あなたの音楽, but it's usually more natural to avoid あなた and use their real name instead (〇〇さんの音楽, 〇〇先生の曲, etc) even if you're directly talking to them.